# How to end a launcher completely?

Tags: android

My application works as a launcher. But, I guess I did something wrong by making it a launcher. For instance, the user selects my application as **Default Launcher** (clicks 'Always'). However, when the user exits from the application, it appears again, because it's the default launcher. How can I fix it?

```
<activity
      android:name="com.comeks.cocuktablet.Main"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleInstance"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The code comes from my manifest. I also want to make **MAIN** activity launcher.

**Edit:**
I realized my exact error. I also wrote a code to start my app on boot. The problem is that when I close my device and open it again, I cannot exit from it.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.  Are you asking how to change the default application for an intent?  Because that's something the user controls, via settings.

Comment: I edited the question. Hope, it became more clear.

Comment: You made your application a LAUNCHER and it means that it will act like all other LAUNCHER apps. Every time user presses home button, launcher app (here your app) will starts. If you want to just start your app at the start-up, register a BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast receiver and launch your app at the device start-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your all answers. I solved my problem by calling Android's home launcher while exiting from app.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

from intent-filter

Comment: I changed my code by removing the lines that you've given. But I couldn't debug it on my tablet yet. As soon as I try it, I'll notice here. Thank you...

Comment: I tried it but when I remove these lines, the launcher doesn't work.