# I cannot close my launcher app after startup

Tags: android

My application works as a launcher and also it starts on startup. However, something is wrong with it. For instance, I install my application on device, and open it by selecting Always button (as default launcher). There is no problem until here. However, if I reboot my device (it opens on startup, as I said before), the application opens. But when I want to close it, I cannot do that. It opens again.
This is my Manifest file:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
    android:name="com.comeks.cocuktablet.Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This is **BootUpReceiver.java**:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Main.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  Both are not needed either it may be a launcher or default... this might not be a problem sometimes any way check it

Comment: you asked essentially the same question yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885626/how-to-end-a-launcher-completely And to disable the launcher functionality the user will have to go to Settings->Manage Apps->YourApp->Clear Defaults. After they press the clear defaults button the next time they press home button they will be given the pop up that shows all avaialbe launchers including the stock one (and yours)

Comment: @Arju Thanks for your answer. I tried it but when I remove one of these 4 lines in intent-filter, it doesn't work.

Comment: @FoamyGuy You're right but when I wrote it yesterday, I didn't know what my problem is, certainly. Today, I realized. I cannot clear default. Because in startup, it must run as default launcher. But if I can clear the default in codes, I may solve it, I guess.

Comment: Your problem is when u close it ,its not getting closed is it?

Comment: I'm sorry. In title, I wrote 'before startup'. I edited it as 'after startup' now. My problem is that when I reboot my device, my app starts (as normal), but when I want to exit, I cannot do it. It closes but appears again (because it's default launcher). I think if I can clear the defaults automatically in codes, it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PackageManager to clear your own application of its defaults, put this inside your onCreate():

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("com.your.package.name");
```

and fill in your own package name. That should clear the launcher default from your app, the next time they press home button they should be shown the choices of which app to use.

Comment: That's the code what I want. Thank you. But I cannot solve my problem still. Because my aim is user not to choose the default launcher after startup. This is for children. I guess I made a logical mistake...

Comment: The error must be that Android doesn't start it's own launcher on startup. Because before I reboot the device, it works fine. 'After' I reboot it, it doesn't work...